# How can I calculate the average of each days record using awk?

Tags: awk

I need to print separately the average record ($1) for each respective days ($2) .

The data looks:

```
400 1
420 2
390 3
370 1
400 2
410 3
415 4
450 1
430 2
420 3
415 4
```

Out put file looks:

```
406.67 1
416.67 2
406.67 3
415    4
```

i have tried this code but it gives me error message.

```
awk '{sum1[$2] += $1; count1[$2]++}; END{ for (id in sum1)                                                              { print id, sum1[id]/coun1[id] } }' file.txt
```

Comment: @Alula you were pretty close... just a typo `coun1` should be `count1`... also order is reversed, but that is easy to fix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alula- If you are not worried about the order of the output(means it should be same as Input_file) then following may help you in same.

```
awk '{A[$2]=A[$2]+$1;B[$2]++} END{for(i in A){printf("%.2f,%d\n", A[i]/B[i],i)}}' Input_file
```

Or if you have the same data as shown like Input_file and you need in the same sorted order as per your Input_file, then you could try following.

```
awk '{A[$2]=A[$2]+$1;B[$2]++} END{for(i in A){printf("%.2f,%d\n", A[i]/B[i],i)}}'  Input_file | sort -t, -k2
```

I hope this helps you.